# SQL code to check if a field in one table exists in another table in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 2 tables "A" and "B" in an Access Database.

There's a column/field in A called "A_ID" with an ID number, and there's a column in B called "B_name" with a name (the name is a short text that could contain an ID number from A_ID)

Also, there's a column in A called "OBE" (for obsolete). OBE is a boolean True/False data type.

I want to write an Update Query with SQL that looks at each ID number in A_ID and checks if it exist somewhere in each B_name of table B. If an ID number in A_ID doesn't exist in any B_name, I want OBE to be set to "True" for that row.

(Each ID number is exclusive and would not exist in multiple B_names)

I hope to make the Update Query run upon clicking a button on a form, or does an Update Query automatically update?

This is what I have so far, and it returns "Syntax error in FROM clause":

```
SELECT *
FROM A
JOIN B
WHERE LOCATE (A.A_ID, B.B_name) > 0
SET A.OBE = True
```

I've also tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
JOIN B
WHERE A.A_ID LIKE CONCAT ('%', B.B_name, '%')
Set A.OBE = True
```

Edit (added context per June's comment):

Thanks for the comment, I agree. So the A_ID numbers look like "S5490", "S5491", "S5491R1", "S5491R2", "S5491R3", "S5492", "I5490", "I5491", etc. etc.

So basically they start with an S or I, have 4 digits, then they could have revisions at the end: "R1", "R2", etc.

The 4-digit number doesn't repeat unless there's a new revision (R) or if the ID starts with a different letter (S or I)

The B_name column varies a lot but it would look something like "Super Cool Product #S5479 Yeah!" or "Super Cool Product-S5479R1-Yeah!" and the text that appears before/after the ID within in the name would never resemble any other ID number and would never repeat an ID number

Comment: The [JOIN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/join-tables-and-queries-3f5838bd-24a0-4832-9bc1-07061a1478f6) needs an ON clause. Use the query designer in Access to make your query. Concatenation in Access is done with `&` (unless you have a pass-through query, then you will have to use the SQL dialect of the back-end).

Comment: Furthermore there is no function called LOCATE in MsAccess; check the documentation for searching one string in another (INSTR). If you want to update the data in a table you use the UPDATE statement; check the documentation for UPDATE SQL statement.

Comment: Apparently these tables do not have a relationship and a direct JOIN is not possible. Without JOIN ON clauses, resulting dataset will be a Cartesian output and cannot be edited. InStr won't really work. If A_ID is a number type, value of 1 will match to `A1A`, `A12A`, `A111A`, etc.; if text then value of `James` will match to `Jameson`, `Jamestown`, etc. Edit question to show sample data of A_ID and B_name fields. This will probably require VBA function.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently these tables do not have a relationship and a direct JOIN is not possible. Without JOIN ON clauses, resulting dataset will be a Cartesian output and cannot be edited. Be aware Cartesian output can perform very slowly with large dataset. Consider:

Query1:
`SELECT A.A_ID, B.B_name, InStr([B_name],[A_ID]) AS C FROM A, B;`

Query2 (assuming A_ID is a text field):
`UPDATE A SET OBE = Nz(DSum("C","Query1","A_ID='" & [A_ID] & "'"),0) = 0;`

However, use of InStr() might produce undesired results. If A_ID is a number type, value of 1 will match to `A1A`, `A12A`, `A111A`, etc.; if text then value of `James` will match to `Carla Jameson`, `Jamestown Ave`, etc.

Comment: This seemed to work, thank you so much! The only issue I'm facing now is, say ID "S1888R1" exists in B_name but "S1888" doesn't. This Update Query would keep both as OBE = False, even though S1888 should be True.  Any ideas on how to rectify this? Could it be solved with some kind of SQL if-statement for ID's without a revision (R) to exclude cases in B_name where an R and then another number follow the ID?

(The same problem could be said for another example: say "S1888R11" exists, and "S1888R1" doesn't, but luckily in my database no revision goes above R9)

Comment: This is the undesirable result I alluded to in my answer. I do not have a resolution. Fuzzy pattern matching is notoriously difficult to wrangle. Pitfalls of bad data.

Comment: It turns out that there actually are some cases where text like "S1888" exists in B_name that's referencing something other than the ID number. Luckily the ID number always comes after the text "ID-" in B_name, so it seems like the only way to do this is to somehow go through B_name and extract the ID number through some fancy SQL or a VBA script. VBA script seems easier but idk if it is possible to create a query out of a table column with VBA

Comment: Yes, VBA custom function could pull ID from string. Consistency of string structure is critical. The trick is figuring out end of the ID in sting. If ID was always followed by a space, that would be ideal but you show example followed by hyphen. How many variations could there be? Query can call a function placed in general module.

Comment: Actually, after looking at samples again, finding start of ID string would be tricky as well as determining the end. There is no consistency.

Comment: Yes I'm going to explore writing a vba script that contains some SQL queries. In order to make this macro run faster, I'm also going to not re-check ID that were marked as OBE and were made before a certain date.

Comment: Hey @June7 I'm trying to recreate your queries in vba, I have: dim qry1 as string *next line* qr1 = "SELECT A.A_ID, B.B_name, InStr([B_name],[A_ID]) AS C" & _ *next line* "FROM A, B;" *next line* DoCmd.RunSQL qry1 ..... but when I run this it is says "Run-time error '3141': The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect." Any ideas?

Comment: Need a space in front of `FROM`: `" FROM A, B;"` or after the preceding `C` so text doesn't just run together. Or put it all on one line - it's not very long statement.

Comment: But SELECT sql are not Run, they are used to open recordsets. Action SQL (DELETE, UPDATE, INSERT) are Run. Building this SELECT in VBA makes no sense.